# Running separate epochs for fit_one_cycle function in fastai

Tags: fast-ai

I am trying to run different epochs of `fit_one_cycle` function separately; saving the model, loading it and starting a new epoch:

```
learn = language_model_learner(data, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5, pretrained=False).to_fp16()
learn.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Language Model/language_model')
learn.load_encoder('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Language Model/model_encoder');
lr = 1e-3
lr *= bs/48  # Scale learning rate by batch size
learn.unfreeze()
learn.fit_one_cycle(1, lr, moms=(0.8,0.7))
learn.save('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Language Model/language_model')
learn.save_encoder('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Language Model/model_encoder')
```

Question: how I should change the `learning rate` after each epoch?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Discriminative Layer Training](https://docs.fast.ai/basic_train.html#Discriminative-layer-training) which uses different learning rates for different layers in the model.

1. Create layer groups of the model using

```
# creates 3 layer groups with start, middle and end groups
learn.split(lambda m: (m[0][6], m[1]))

# only randomly initialized head now trainable
learn.freeze()
```

**Note:** No need to manually split the layers `fit_one_cycle` automatically splits randomly.

2. Manually setting LR rate and weight decay for each layer group

```
# all layers now trainable
learn.unfreeze()

# optionally, separate LR and WD for each group for 5 epochs
learn.fit_one_cycle(5, max_lr=slice(1e-5,1e-3), wd=(1e-4,1e-4,1e-1))
```